# I have two imageviews but when I call on one imageview to set image it set image same image both of them

Tags: java, android, xml

I have two imageviews back to back. when I set image on first imageview it also set same image on next image view and when I change image from one image view it also change that image from other.How can I fix it. Please help me. Thank you in advance.
Related code is:

```
`    ImageView cpic,psymbol;
     private static final int PICK_IMAGE=100;
     private static final int SET_IMAGE=100;
     Uri imageUri,simageUri;
     cpic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openGallery();
        }
    });
    psymbol.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openGallary();
        }


    });

}

private void openGallery() {
    Intent Gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(Gallery,PICK_IMAGE);

}
private void openGallary(){
    Intent Gallary = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(Gallary,SET_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==PICK_IMAGE){
        imageUri=data.getData();



       InputStream imageinput = null;
        try {
            imageinput=getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            cpic.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageinput));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==SET_IMAGE){
        simageUri=data.getData();

        InputStream inputimage = null;
        try {
            inputimage=getContentResolver().openInputStream(simageUri);
            psymbol.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputimage));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

`

Comment: please add your xml too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
 private static final int PICK_IMAGE=100;
 private static final int SET_IMAGE=100;
```

change the value of one of these variables because in `onActivityResult` both `if` statements are executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final int PICK_IMAGE=100;
private static final int SET_IMAGE=100;
```

You are using same request code for both of them. So you must use different request codes.

So, you should do like this -

```
private static final int PICK_IMAGE=100;
private static final int SET_IMAGE=101;


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==PICK_IMAGE){
        imageUri=data.getData();

        InputStream imageinput = null;
        try {
            imageinput=getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            cpic.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageinput));
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==SET_IMAGE){
        simageUri=data.getData();

        InputStream inputimage = null;
        try {
            inputimage=getContentResolver().openInputStream(simageUri);
            psymbol.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputimage));

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AmnaNaeem you can't accept both the answers. if you try to accept another answer this will uncheck the previously checked answer. So, you have an option to select only one answer. Please select the one which is relavant and providw you more knowledge and description about the problem.